# Проверка переполнения при делении

Tags: ассемблер

Подскажите, как в программе сделать проверку переполнения регистра?

Код ASM:

```
mov   ax,4000H  ;делимое
mov   bl,2      ;делитель - байт, поэтому частное - тоже байт (AL)
div   bl        ;4000H/2 = 2000H, что не умещается в байте AL
                ;поэтому выполняется прерывание INT 00H
```

И заодно проверку деления на ноль )

```
mov   bx,0
div   bx
```

Comment: 1. Очевидный способ избавиться от переполнения - делить пару регистров dx:ax на bx.
2. Проверка деления на 0:
    * Простой и очевидный способ - проверять делитель на ноль **до** деления.
    * Сложный способ - добавить свой обработчик прерывания. Тоже и с проверкой переполнения.

Comment: @insolor можете пояснить

>1. Очевидный способ избавиться от переполнения - делить пару регистров dx:ax на bx.

? 

Не очень понял.

Comment: @Роман Пономаренко,

    mov dx, 0
    mov ax, 4000H
    mov bx, 2
    div bx
    ; частное в ax, остаток в dx

Comment: @insolor а что если делимое будет больше, чем 4000H (например, 65000) результат же не поместиться в регистр ax;

Answer (score 1):

Делите числа одинаковой размерности (например, `al` - делимое, `bl` - делитель, `ah` - 0 или `ax` - делимое, `bx` - делитель, `dx` - 0), тогда переполнения не будет. Я бы не стал из-за такой мелочи связываться с переопределением обработчика прерывания.

Ну а если вам нужно делить именно на 2 (или на степень 2), то замените деление на двоичный сдвиг (`shr`).

В вашем случае перед делением нужно проверить, чтобы `ah` было строго меньше, чем `bl`, тогда частное должно уместиться в `al`.

Аналогично, при делении `dx:ax` на `bx`: `dx` должно быть меньше `bx`.

Comment: @insolor, спасибо за ваш комментарий к удаленному на данный момент ответу. Теперь все стало ясно.

Comment: @0xFFh, я сам о таком поведении узнал только вчера.